# Get the current selected item or null from item list

Tags: rxjs

Given a list of item

```
items = [
  {id: 1, selected: false},
  {id: 2, selected: false}
]
```

How do I construct an observable's selector that returns either the current item with selected=true or null if no item is selected?

**First attempt**:

```
items
.flatMap(item => item)
.filter(item => item.selected)
.startWith(null)
```

Works fine on initial load and upon selecting an item. But as soon as all items get unselected again, it won't emit null - which makes sense since the filter() operator doesn't pass. What I'm missing here is the ability to set 'null' as a fallback default value that would get emitted in this case.

**Second attempt**, using first() with default value 'null':

```
items
.flatMap(item => item)
.first(item => item.selected, null)
```

This too works fine on initial load but it won't get executed on any subsequent change events. To my understanding, this is because first() finishes the stream after its initial run is complete.

**Final (working) attempt**:

```
items
.map((items) => {
  selectedItems = items.filter(item => item.selected);
  return selectedItems.length ? selectedItems : [null] 
})
.flatMap(item => item)
```

This does what I need, however I'm wondering if there's another way to express this logic using only rxjs operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `scan` operator which can emit the current state (or toggle). See this jsfiddle which does almost what you want (filter items based on state and return current state) https://jsfiddle.net/crunchie84/n1x06016/6/

Comment: Thanks Mark for your example. I see how you can achieve this with using `scan`.